# Не работает --standalone в nuitka

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, nuitka

Вот сама ошибка:

```
C:\Users\Админ\Desktop>nuitka --standalone  2.py
Nuitka:INFO: Starting Python compilation.
Nuitka:INFO: Completed Python level compilation and optimization.
Nuitka:INFO: Generating C source code for backend compiler.
Nuitka:INFO: Running data composer tool for optimal constant value handling.
Nuitka:INFO: Running C level backend compilation via Scons.
Nuitka-Scons:INFO: Backend C compiler: cl (cl).
Nuitka-Scons:WARNING: Didn't find clcache for C level caching, follow Nuitka user manual description.
Nuitka-Scons:WARNING: You are not using clcache.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Админ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\nuitka\__main__.py", line 196, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Админ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\nuitka\__main__.py", line 189, in main
    MainControl.main()
  File "C:\Users\Админ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\nuitka\MainControl.py", line 763, in main
    standalone_entry_points=getStandardEntryPoints(),
  File "C:\Users\Админ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\nuitka\freezer\Standalone.py", line 1419, in copyUsedDLLs
    and not Options.getWindowsDependencyTool() == "depends.exe",
  File "C:\Users\Админ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\nuitka\freezer\Standalone.py", line 1296, in detectUsedDLLs
    standalone_entry_point.package_name,
  File "C:\Users\Админ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\nuitka\utils\ThreadedExecutor.py", line 45, in submit
    self.results.append(function(*args))
  File "C:\Users\Админ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\nuitka\freezer\Standalone.py", line 1266, in addDLLInfo
    update_cache=update_cache,
  File "C:\Users\Админ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\nuitka\freezer\Standalone.py", line 1241, in detectBinaryDLLs
    update_cache=update_cache,
  File "C:\Users\Админ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\nuitka\freezer\Standalone.py", line 1050, in detectBinaryPathDLLsWindowsDependencyWalker
    _parseDependsExeOutput(output_filename, result)
  File "C:\Users\Админ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\nuitka\freezer\Standalone.py", line 888, in _parseDependsExeOutput
    _parseDependsExeOutput2(getFileContentByLine(filename, encoding="latin1"), result)
  File "C:\Users\Админ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\nuitka\freezer\Standalone.py", line 873, in _parseDependsExeOutput2
    assert os.path.isfile(dll_filename), (dll_filename, line)
AssertionError: ('c:\\users\\\x04\x04\x04\x04\x04\x04\x04\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\python37.dll', '     [  6] c:\\users\\\x04\x04\x04\x04\x04\x04\x04\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\PYTHON37.DLL')
```

Comment: Судя по ошибке, не находит файл python37.dll, и похоже что проблема в том, что у вас Python установлен в папку, в пути которой есть кириллица. Попробуйте переустановить Python в папку, не содержащую кириллицу в пути.

Comment: @insolor Спс щас попробую и да у меня файл python37.dll почему то появился на рабочем столе